# Does tweepy handle rate limit - code 429

Tags: python, tweepy

I have a wrapper class for the twitter authentication where there is a line:

```
self.__api = tweepy.API(self.auth,
                        wait_on_rate_limit=False,
                        wait_on_rate_limit_notify=False)
```

When I instantiate the wrapper class to get api object of twitter:

```
api_call = myWrapper(self.CONSUMER_KEY, self.CONSUMER_SECRET,
                          self.ACCESS_KEY, self.ACCESS_SECRET, True, True)
```

Based on my understanding setting up wait_on_rate_limit and wait_on_rate_limit_notify to True should default take care the rate issue (Based on tweepy documentation).

But I get following error when I am iterating over list of users and try to get their timeline **(~3400)**
`tweepy.error.TweepError: Twitter error response: status code = 429`

I tried following:

```
remaining = int(api_call.api.last_response.getheader('X-Rate-Limit-Remaining'))
```

but it says `last_response` attribute is not available.

Answer (score 0):

No, you have to create a handler for this exception.